# Shell way to get specific text based on condition

Tags: shell-script, cron, text

Using shell script I am making a db call on database VM and I am getting and storing the query response into a .txt file. Which looks like below:

```
X folder Check:
Number of Files on X Outbound
17
Y folder Check:
Number of Files on Y Outbound
17
Z folder Check:
Number of Files on Z Outbound
18
```

Now for each of the X,Y and Z. I am basically receiving files(counts) on their respective locations. So I am expecting to get "18" files for each X,Y and Z. Now using shell I want to be able to know/store the folders for which I didn't receive 18 files.

Example: here in the above case I should get that I am missing files for X and Y folders.

Comment: Changing the query (to the database) to only return the folder names where the number of queries is other than 18, is that an option? Or doing a separate query for that?

Comment: I think that will not be the way - as there are certain security issue with db call itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n 'N;N;/\n18$/!s/ folder Check:\n.*\n/ /p'
```

on that text would output:

```
X 17
Y 17
```

- `-n` tells `sed` not to print the pattern space by default (we only print the ones we want with the `p` flag to the `s` command)
- `N;N`: we pull the two next lines into the pattern space, we we process 3 lines at a time in a 3 line pattern space.
- `/\n18/!`: if the pattern space does not (`!`) end (`$`) in `<newline>18`
- `s/folder Check:\n.*\n//p`: remove the part between the folder name and the count and `p`rint. You could also only retain the folder name (`s/ folder Check:\n.*//p`), or dump the full three lines (`p`) depending on what you want exactly.

Same with `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/ folder Check:$/, ""); folder = $0; getline; getline; count = $0}
     count != 18 {print folder, count}'
```

Comment: Could not get any answer more perfect than this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{n=(NR%3)} n==1{folder=$1} (n==0) && ($0!=18){print folder, $0}' file
X 17
Y 17
```